# Responsive Web Design Automation Testing strategies

Tags: responsive-design, automation

I have gone through various websites before asking this question. I got only solution as Galen framework. But it requires lot of details from developers to cross check and also we need to know its spec language. Iam planning to come up with a frame work using webdriver+sikuli+Js .Can some one suggest me how to plan the strategy for automating Responsive web design sites?